# How to distinguish kernel stack and user stack in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, kernel

I tried to use gdb to analyze the coredump file. The stack frame was damaged so the *bt* instruction could not be used directly. I tried to use *rbp* to backtrace manually. The *rbp* of my first stack frame is 0x7fxxxxxxxxxx, so I suspect it is in kernel mode.

**How should I return to the user stack?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I suspect it is in kernel mode.

Your suspicion is wrong:

1. GDB will *never* show you any kernel-mode stack when you are not debugging the kernel itself (which is the case here).
2. The value of `RSP` (and `RBP`) for the main thread of an `x86_64` program *typically* looks like this: `0x7fffffffd8b0` -- there is *nothing* "kernely" about it.

Comment: So I can directly get the rbp address of the previous stack frame by accessing the memory corresponding to the current rbp address?